# How to popen with varied optional arguments

Tags: python, arguments, popen

I have a process I need to run in python and get the output of. How do I run it so that the user can specify optional arguments that can be run on the process. This is what my function looks like so far.

```py
    async def analyze_target(self, target, batchSize, delay, maxdepth, maxurls, maxwait, recursive, useragent, htmlmaxcols, htmlmaxrows):

        cmd = "wappalyzer"
        if batchSize != "":
            cmd = cmd + " --batch-size=" + batchSize

        if delay != "":
            cmd = cmd + " --delay=" + delay

        if maxdepth != "":
            cmd = cmd + " --max-depth=" + maxdepth

        if maxurls != "":
            cmd = cmd + " --max-urls=" + maxurls

        if maxwait != "":
            cmd = cmd + " --max-wait=" + maxwait

        if recursive == True:
            cmd = cmd + " --recursive"

        if useragent != "":
            cmd = cmd + " --user-agent=" + useragent

        if htmlmaxcols != "":
            cmd = cmd + " --html-max-cols=" + htmlmaxcols

        if htmlmaxrows != "":
            cmd = cmd + " --html-max-rows=" + htmlmaxrows

        cmd = cmd + " " + target
        
        p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
        
        tmp = p.stdout.read()

        self.logger.info(tmp)

        p_status = p.wait()

        """
        Returns log of what was wappalyzed
        """
        message = f"target {target} has been wappalyzed with output {tmp}"

        # This logs to the docker logs
        self.logger.info(message)
        return tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of [`Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen), `args`, supports a single string or a Sequence. So you could append Optional arguments to a `list` for example

```py
cmd = [cmd, *args]
```

Or you could also use **kwargs ([dictionary displays](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#dictionary-displays)) (which basically treat any named argument as a dictionary) in the arguments of your function and do something like this:

```py
def analyze_target(..., **kwargs):
    ...

    for key, value, in kwargs.items():
        cmd += f" --{key.replace('_', '-')}={value}"  # change name since dashes cannot be used as names

    ...

# would look like this:
analyze_target(..., additional_argument='test')

# cmd: all other arguments + --additional-argument=test
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not build a string. Simply build a list containing the name of the command and its arguments as separate elements.

```
async def analyze_target(self, target, batchSize, delay, maxdepth, maxurls, maxwait, recursive, useragent, htmlmaxcols, htmlmaxrows):

    cmd = ["wappalyzer"]
    if batchSize != "":
        cmd.append("--batch-size=" + batchSize)

    if delay != "":
        cmd.append("--delay=" + delay)

    if maxdepth != "":
        cmd.append("--max-depth=" + maxdepth)

    if maxurls != "":
        cmd.append("--max-urls=" + maxurls)

    if maxwait != "":
        cmd.append("--max-wait=" + maxwait)

    if recursive:
        cmd.append("--recursive")

    if useragent != "":
        cmd.append("--user-agent=" + useragent)

    if htmlmaxcols != "":
        cmd.append("--html-max-cols=" + htmlmaxcols)

    if htmlmaxrows != "":
        cmd.append("--html-max-rows=" + htmlmaxrows)

    cmd.append(target)
    
    # Drop the shell=True, so that command is executed
    # directly, without shell involvement
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    
    ...
```